# How to stop interval on mouse over in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
<script>
  var pics = [ 
  "image/city (1).jpg",
    "image/city (2).jpg", 
    "image/city (3).jpg", 
    "image/city (4).jpg",
    "image/city (5).jpg",
    "image/city (6).jpg",
    "image/city (7).jpg",
    "image/city (8).jpg",
    "image/beach.jpg",
    "image/beach2.jpg"
  ];
  
  var inval;
  var photo;

  function carousel() {
    photo = document.getElementById('carousel-pics'); 
    var i = -1;
    inval = setInterval(function() {
        i++;
        if (i >= pics.length) {
          i = 0;
        }
        photo.src = pics[i];
       }, 1000);   
      }      
      
      function removeInterval() {
        clearInterval(inval);
     }

  document.getElementById('carousel-pics').addEventListener("mouseover", removeInterval);
</script>

<div class="polaroid" id="carousel-div" style="width:1000px; height:600px;">
  <img id="carousel-pics" src="image/city (1).jpg" alt="athens" style="width:1000px; height:600px;">
 
</div>
```

The code above is a slide show for some photos. I want to stop the slide show when i mouse over the photo. But it does not work. If i add a button to stop the slide show,  it works but when i use mouse over event, it does not work.

Comment: I've used exactly same code (I've only changed images) as you posted and [it works](https://jsfiddle.net/40kzg2nc/1/). Could you please provide more informations? How about `console` or some `styles` which could override your carousel (is "mouseover" event called? Log it).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066042/jquery-mouseover-event-not-working-right

Comment: Oh, so weird! This is the only script on the page! On console it says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at index.html:160

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem I see here is `<img>` tag is below `script` tag. When you try to attach `addEventListener` at `document.getElementById('carousel-pics')`, it wouldn't work because `document.getElementById('carousel-pics')` at this point is null. Try keeping `script` below html.

```html
<script>
 let ele1 = document.getElementById("test")
 console.log('[1]' , ele1)
</script>

<div id="test"></div>

<script>
 let ele2 = document.getElementById("test")
 console.log('[2]' , ele2)
</script>
```

Above is code representation of the same. You can see in 1st script the element is `null` while in the second one it's not

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned,

1. Change the order. Body div first than script.
2. Change the name of the images, it is broken

sample is given below

```js
var pics = [
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1555797487-a1f30b5d8d55?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=589&q=400",
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533158307587-828f0a76ef46?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80",
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1555797487-a1f30b5d8d55?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=589&q=400"
];

const photo = document.getElementById("carousel-pics");
function carousel() {
  let index = -1;
  const inval = setInterval(function() {
    index++;
    if (index >= pics.length) (index = 0);
    photo.src = pics[index];
  }, 1000);
  return () => clearInterval(inval)
}
const unsubsriber = carousel()

photo.addEventListener("mouseover", unsubsriber);
```

```html
<div class="polaroid" id="carousel-div" style="width:1000px; height:600px;">
  <img id="carousel-pics" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1555797487-a1f30b5d8d55?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=589&q=400" alt="athens" style="width:1000px; height:600px;">
 
</div>
```